# Ionic using IdentityServer4 as IDP

Tags: angular, api, typescript, ionic-framework, identityserver4

I got a simple task project i built in spare time.
Consists of:

- API server
- IdentityServer4 Provider
- Angular Frontend (not angularjs)

I am now trying to expand this by incorporating a mobile app. In this case i built a simple app in Ionic that displays tasks.
I want  to now implement authentication so it can obtain tasks relevant to that user from the API.

I been looking around but cannot find any explanation on how to do this or any examples that demonstrate this.

End state it will be a Android app.

Any assistance is appreciated.

**Update 1:**

I've looked into leveraging oidc-client but it doesn't seem to activate the browser function properly when ported to Android. Still though haven't found sufficient informatino on this as to proper approach and how to do this.

**Update 2: Feature Request to Ionic**
Since there seems to be number of people affected by this i have raised feature request with Ionic team in Github.
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14499

Please vote and comment on it.

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: no, the only way i can see this being successful is to do the same approach as Firebase and others. Use custom restful call to IDP to obtain token. This goes against standards of OpenID, but only way to make this work effectively.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up publishing the ionic app as a website but I’m running into Cors issues.  Due to a plug-in I’m using so I’ll have to rewrite this to use a new login component

Comment: I've raised this request to Ionic team on Github https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14499. Please feel free to add to it and bring it to their attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're creating a mobile app, you're going to want to use the Authorization Code or Hybrid flows, along with [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636). If you haven't already, check out [RFC 8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252), which details best current practices for OAuth (and in turn OpenID Connect) and native apps.

Unfortunately, oidc-client only supports the implicit flow. For an Ionic app, I would recommend using [openid-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openid-client) since this allows the usage of both more appropriate flows, but also PKCE.

As far as I know, there are no public examples of Ionic using OpenID Connect, however, I do have a customer successfully using Ionic & the library I've listed above.

**Update**:
oidc-client-js now supports Authorization Code + PKCE and is therefore suitable for ionic apps.

Comment: Thanks mate will look into it. Btw you got great tuts, helped me get off the ground.

Comment: As an update to this, oidc-client-js now supports auth code + PKCE

Comment: this is scary, i was jut looking at this question and you popped up

Comment: @ScottBrady are you sure, this working with Ionic ?

Comment: Yep. In fact, oidc-client-js now supports the auth code flow + PKCE and is also suitable for ionic

Comment: @Scott Brady could you please send me the any integration example of code flow + PKCE to ionic 4/5

Comment: @ScottBrady I am also trying to connect my angular-ionic project to my identity server 4 with oidc-client - library. The redirect is not working, redirect popup fails all the time. Is there any example? thx